# How to concatenate two arrays without changing order in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have 3 arrays. Lets say the first array has 3 elements, second array has 2 elements, and third array has 5 elements. When I concatenate them the `array[3]` will go to first element of the second array, `array[6]` will go to the second element of third array, because I first concatenate the first array with the second. If I concatenate the first array with the third, then concatenate the second array, `array[3]` will point to the first element of the third array.

Comment: can you please provide some examples of what your three arrays look like and what your expected result is?

Answer (score 4):

don't understand your content, but according do your subject , I think below may help.

```
const a = [1,2,3]
const b = [4,5]
const c = [...a, ...b] // [1,2,3,4,5]
```